# Moving a ball with accelerometer Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, accelerometer, gyroscope

I'm learning for windows phone 8, and i wanted to write an app where i can move an image using the accelerometer, not a level detector, i want it to move just like in labyrinth games. How would i make this happen? Does anyone have any good samples/turials/explainations or similar? I have been searching the web for two days now, trying to be integrating it. It will be used for a very simple learning-game for myself since i learn alot from samples. I have started my project as a normal app, since this is what i absolutely like to develop with, the UI design, etc, i have already created a basic UI, and also things the ball can collide into, things like arcs and stuff(controls). I am writing it in C#, i also got a little knowledge from java game development (not very much).

Thanks alot!

Comment: Why not work through the samples that are available to learn the platform, rather than spend 2 days looking for a sample which doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any samples (AFAIK) that do exactly what you describe.

If you really want an accelerometer/labyrinth game, there's a C++ sample at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Marble-Maze-sample-for-c9f3706b

Alternatively, there a lot of other samples to learn from.
These should keep you busy for a while: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/

Comment: Yeah, you're probably both right, gonna learn the platform and then do the game